# Sorting and searching in an array with struct by different struct elements

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, search, struct

I would like  to sort an array of structs by different variables and then search by these variables without resorting the whole array with the struct elements.

I would also like to change values within the arrays of struct elements having an effect on the order of the array struct elements.

I tried the following as an example:

```
public struct myStruct : IComparable<myStruct>
        {
            public int number { get; set; }
            public double high { get; set; }
            public double low { get; set; }
            public int year { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(myStruct other)
            {
                return number.CompareTo(other.number);
            }
        }   
        
        private myStruct[] TestArrayStruct = new myStruct[0];
        
        protected voidAddElement(int number, double high, double low, int year)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref TestArrayStruct,TestArrayStruct.Length+1);
            TestArrayStruct[TestArrayStruct.Length-1].number=number;
            TestArrayStruct[TestArrayStruct.Length-1].high=high;
            TestArrayStruct[TestArrayStruct.Length-1].low=low;
            TestArrayStruct[TestArrayStruct.Length-1].year=year;
        }
        
        protected void main()
        {
            int NextHit=0;
                
            AddElement(5, 20, 10, 2020);
            AddElement(9, 40, 15, 2022);
            AddElement(11, 25, 10, 2023);
            AddElement(15, 20, 5, 2019);
        
            TestArrayStruct = TestArrayStruct.OrderBy(a => a.number).ToArray();
            myStruct target = new myStruct  { number = 9 }; // Creating search element for Number 95
            NextHit=Array.BinarySearch(TestArrayStruct, target);
            
            Print("Element: " + NextHit + "  Number: " + TestArrayStruct[NextHit].number);
            
            Print("Changing Variable Number ...");
            TestArrayStruct[NextHit].number=10;
            TestArrayStruct = TestArrayStruct.OrderBy(a => a.number).ToArray();
            
            target = new myStruct  { number = 10 };
            NextHit=Array.BinarySearch(TestArrayStruct, target);
            Print("NexHit=" + NextHit);
            Print("Element: " + NextHit + "  Number: " + TestArrayStruct[NextHit].number);      
        
        }
```

`

How can I sort by each element number, high, low, year of the struct of arrays, so that I can start a binary search by number, high, low, year without resorting the array each time?

Kind regards,
Gerik

I tried the above, but I am looking for a best practice to sort the array using a reference to the "original" array. I do not want to copy the array, then sort each array and keeping then 4 arrays in sync. Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: How many items will you be searching in? How fast do you need it to be? How fast is a simple linear search? Unless you have a huge amount of items, a linear search should perform just fine. *If* you have a huge amount of items, you should perhaps consider using a database.

Comment: I will be searching within in about 100000 items. The question is how can I sort in different ways? In the sample above I can only search by number and not by high, low or year. How can I have 4 sorted references without resorting the original array each time?

Comment: I don't think this efficiently possible without maintaining an index for each searchable property. Consider using an in-memory SQLite database.

Comment: Note that the problem becomes trivial if you scrap the possibility to update searchable properties or if such updates don't happen often.

Comment: I need to expand the array of struct many times, so I need to update anyway. I guess I then need to maintain 4 separate indexes in parallel to the main array where I keep the value to be sorted and the unsorted main array element to point to, right?

Comment: Correct. But it sounds like you also need to support insert, not just update. Otherwise I don't see why you would need to expand so often. Is the number of `myStruct`s not known beforehand?

Comment: Indeed, I do not need to insert. I will try to initiate with a minimum size to try to accelerate by avoiding resizing of the array. Thank you.

Comment: You still have not mentioned how fast you need this to be. Doing a linear search thru 100k items takes about *530 μs* for me. Is that *really* to slow for you? And in that case, what are you really doing? A in-memory database might be able to do better, but then you need to balance the cost of updating indices against the search cost.